# gradient descent (testing difference in error)

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

High there,

So i'm trying to write a programme to execute the gradient descent algorithm on a sample data set with one y output and several x inputs. rather than having the user set the number of "epochs" over which to update the coefficients based on the error, id like to iteratively test the updated error against the old error, and stop the function when the level of difference falls below some tolerance (probably set by the user). Am i going about this in the right way? and if so what might be the best method to use for quantifying the difference between old and new error?

I'm doing this as part of a course on data programming in python by the way.

Any tips appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out that:

The training error is usually not stable after each iteration when you are optimizing with Mini batch Gradient Descent, or Stochastic Gradient Descent or other algorithms depends on the batch size. 
So your approach might lead to early stop or infinite loop.

However, if you are using Batch Gradient Descent, I think your approach might work.

**Edit:**

Stochastic GD means that you calculate error and gradient for only one sample at a time, while in Batch GD, you calculate errors and grads for every sample in the training set.

The disadvantage of BatchGD is that you need to calculate gradient again and again for whole training set (imagine when you have millions training samples).

About your f-values: I think that you can stuck in saddle points (where your function is flat). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point

However, if you still want to implement this approach, I think your "new" error (or new f-values) should be *10 or 20 steps* after the "old" one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid my experience doesn't go as far as knowing the difference between stochastic and batch gd. Could you elaborate. My training data has two variables with one y variable, I was thinking of using f-values.